C++ function as a parameter where its parameter can be passed by value or by reference
I have the following functions where processArray is a generic function that is used to process an array. A function is passed to it as a parameter so that each element can also be processed.
template<typename TItem>
size_t processArray(const TItem* value, const size_t length, size_t (*processItem)(const TItem)) {
    size_t output = length;

    for (auto i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        output += processItem(value[i]);
    }

    return output;
}

size_t processInt(const int value) {
    return value;
}

size_t processString(const std::string& value) {
    return value.length();
}

Then I want to process an array of int and std::string, but I encounter a compilation error (because (*processItem)(const TItem) does not accept a reference type parameter).
// Int
const int intArray[2] { 1, 2 };
const auto intArrayResult = processArray(intArray, 2, processInt); // OK

// String
const std::string strArray[2] { "123", "456" };
const auto strArrayResult = processArray(strArray, 2, processString); // Error: No matching function for call to 'processArray'

However, if I change the declaration of the processItem parameter to size_t (*processItem)(const TItem&) - make it accept the reference type, then I cannot pass processInt.
const int intArray[2] { 1, 2 };
const auto intArrayResult = processArray(intArray, 2, processInt); // Error: No matching function for call to 'processArray'

// String
const std::string strArray[2] { "123", "456" };
const auto strArrayResult = processArray(strArray, 2, processString); // OK

So, does anyone know how processArray can be written so that the function is declared only once and it can accept processItem that can process both value and reference types? Or is there no way to accomplish it?
// NG function declaration is repeated

template<typename TItem>
size_t processArray(const TItem* value, const size_t length, size_t (*processItem)(const TItem));

template<typename TItem>
size_t processArray(const TItem* value, const size_t length, size_t (*processItem)(const TItem&));


Would it be OK for you to have 2 template parameters: template<typename TItem, typename F> size_t processArray(const TItem* value, const size_t length, F processItem) ?

Just go templates all the way and make the function type a template as well:
template<typename TItem, typename Func>
size_t processArray(const TItem* value, const size_t length, Func func) {
    std::size_t output = length;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        output += func(value[i]);
    }

    return output;
}

And you can see it working in this live example.
One caveat with this approach is it will fail if your function is overloaded.  If it is you will need to wrap it in a lambda expression like
const auto intArrayResult = processArray(intArray, 2, [](const auto& val) { return overloaded_function(val); });


If you are solely dealing with plain raw arrays you can also adjust the function to take the array by reference which allows you to not need to pass the size as well.  It also allows you to use a ranged-based for loop.  That would look like
template<typename TItem, std::size_t N, typename Func>
size_t processArray(const TItem (&values)[N], Func func) {
    std::size_t output = N;

    for (const auto& val : values) {
        output += func(val);
    }

    return output;
}


For the suggestion that you made in the second snippet, just template<typename Array, typename Func> size_t processArray(const Array &values, Func func).... would have been enough. Additionally use of std::accumulate makes it beautiful.

@JeJo Do you have an example on how to use accumulate here?  I can't see how to apply it since we aren't adding up the array but adding up the return value of each processed element.  I guess you could go the range way and make a transform_view and then accumulate that, but not sure if that's really what the OP needs.  Without the accumulation of the results for_each seems like the more appropriate algorithm.

No need to overthink, usual std::accumulate will work: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/485Kzvxvs

@JeJo Meh, I'd rather use the ranged based for loop.  Easier to read and understand IMO.

I had a similar issue where I needed to pass a templated value to the template function as it is shown down below, then there is a compilation error:
error: no matching function for call to 'processArray(const int&, const int [2], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'

template<typename Stream, typename TItem, typename Func>
size_t processArray(Stream &stream, const TItem* value, const size_t length, Func func) {
    size_t output = length;

    for (auto i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        output += func(stream, value[i]);
    }

    return output;
}

template<typename Stream>
size_t processString(Stream &stream, const std::string& value) {
    return value.length();
}

template<typename Stream>
size_t processInt(Stream &stream, const int value) {
    return value;
}

The solution is specifying a template of the Stream parameter explicitly:
int main()
{
    MyStream stream(4096);

    // Int
    const int intArray[2] { 1, 2 };
    const auto intArrayResult = processArray(stream, intArray, 2, processInt<MyStream>);

    // String
    const std::string strArray[2] { "123", "456" };
    const auto strArrayResult = processArray(stream, strArray, 2, processString<MyStream>);
}

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/G6KofobrY

Supposed you cannot modify processArray nor processString you can use a lambda:
std::vector<std::string> x(20);
std::cout << processArray(x.data(),x.size(),+[](std::string s){ return processString(s); });

Live Demo
If you can modify them make the type of the callable a template argument as suggested here.
